# Collinearity of triangle vertices on circular paths

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-curves, plane-geometry

Suppose as a function of time, the vertices of a triangle move with constant speed along circular trajectories:
$$
\vec p_i(t) = a_i
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\cos(b_i t+ c_i)\\
\sin(b_i t+ c_i)
\end{array}
\right)
+\vec d_i,
$$
where $i\in\{1,2,3\}$.  All motion is in the plane, that is, $\vec p_i(t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.  Every vertex has its own speed/arc.

**I need the smallest $t^\ast\geq0$ for which $p_1(t^\ast)$, $p_2(t^\ast)$, and $p_3(t^\ast)$ become collinear, if such a $t^\ast$ exists.
Is this computable in closed form?  If not, is there a lightweight algorithm (or convex optimization problem) that would recover $t^\ast$?**

---

So far, all I can think of doing is defining the circles implicitly and writing down a condition for finding a line through all three circles.  But, this does not involve $t$ and already is not a nice formula.

Comment: (this problem would be similar to computing when planets align, but the motion is around three different centers)

Comment: Additionally it's ok to assume the $b_i$'s don't have common integer factors.  So, for example, maybe it's the case that any pair of points on the first two circles is eventually achieved?

Comment: What is $\vec x_i$?

Comment: Oops!  I think there's an easier way to write this --- give me 5 min to correct...

Comment: Fixed!  Sorry about that, had rotation matrices on the brain.

Comment: This problem csn also have no solution (when the radius of the final circles are small you will always find a non degenerate triangle). Use https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/applications.html and let the area equal to 0.

Comment: Yes, there are many cases when a solution does not exist.  The zero area formulation you mention is reasonable, but this system of equation is very difficult to solve!  Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not a system: it is a single equation. You can simplify it a little by translating (zeroing one of the $\vec d_i$) and time shifting (zeroing one of the c_i), but you then have to solve the trig equation. It should not be too hard.

Comment: Not sure finding a root is quite so easy (my apologies for sloppy language).  Each point has its own $cos$ and $sin$ term rotating at an independent rate.  This will be a trigonometric expression with many, many terms!  Is there an algorithm for this?

Answer (score 0):

In case that all b_i are rational numbers, without loss of generality, you can assume b_1, b_2, b_3 are integers. (since you can always do a change of variables to rescale the time t)

Using the form of sin(nx) and cos(nx), see e.g. here
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html

as well as the half angle tangent formula,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula

use the two together, essential you should be able to reduce the determinant constraint "det[p3-p1,p2-p1]=0" as a polynomial equation of tan(t/2).

In summary,
1) first, solving for tan(t/2) by solving a polynomial equation, likely multiple roots will exist.
2) recover t from all possible values of tan(t/2), choose it to be the smallest positive t*.